# How to fix binary search algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++14, binary-search

Ok so i have been learning binary search. My teacher has given me a problem on codeforces and it always fails on test 2. Here is the problem:

In this problem jury has some number x, and you have to guess it. The number x is always an integer from 1 and to n, where n

is given to you at the beginning.

You can make queries to the testing system. Each query is a single integer from 1
to n

. Flush output stream after printing each query. There are two different responses the testing program can provide:

```
the string "<" (without quotes), if the jury's number is less than the integer in your query;
the string ">=" (without quotes), if the jury's number is greater or equal to the integer in your query.
```

When your program guessed the number x
, print string "! x", where x

is the answer, and terminate your program normally immediately after flushing the output stream.

Your program is allowed to make no more than 25 queries (not including printing the answer) to the testing system.

Input

Use standard input to read the responses to the queries.

The first line contains an integer n
(1≤n≤pow(10,6) — maximum possible jury's number.

Following lines will contain responses to your queries — strings "<" or ">=". The i
-th line is a response to your i-th query. When your program will guess the number print "! x", where x

is the answer and terminate your program.

The testing system will allow you to read the response on the query only after your program print the query for the system and perform flush operation.
Output

To make the queries your program must use standard output.

Your program must print the queries — integer numbers xi
(1≤xi≤n), one query per line (do not forget "end of line" after each xi

). After printing each line your program must perform operation flush.

And here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        string s;
        int k=0;
        cin>>n; 
        int min=1,max=n;
        int a;
        while(k==0)
        {
            if(max==min+1)
            {
                cout<<"! "<<min;
                k=1;
                break;
            }
            a=(min+max)/2;
            cout<<a<<endl;
            cin>>s;
            if(s==">=")
                min=a;
            else
                max=a;
                
        }
    }
```

I dont know what test 2 is, but i would be happy to hear ideas as to where my programs is wrong. My guess is its something with the number of guesses. Thanks in advance!

I have tried variations of the loop written above, but they all give the same result.

Comment: Write out a formal invariant that tells what `min` and `max` mean.  In particular, use the words "inclusive" or "exclusive" as appropriate.  Right now it looks like part of your program is using "The unknown number is between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (inclusive)" and part is using "The unknown number is between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive)" and this inconsistency is your bug.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your question.  As a high-reputation user, I still can't see who downvoted, but I can see that there is a close vote for "not including debugging details".  It seems that user overlooked the fact that you don't know the details of the test case that your code was failing.  If you did know what input caused your code to fail, it would certainly be nice to have that included in your question.

Comment: Now that you've found the bug, we can work backwards and figure out what kind of input led to a wrong result.  It is of course where the secret number was equal to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you test A and the output is "<", then you can set max to A-1.

Let's say that for some reason your binary search arrived at the following state:

lo = 5, hi = 6    (correct number should be 6)

It will enter the if(hi == lo + 1) case and return 5 (which is incorrect)

Let me know if that is enough, since it is much better if you adapt your algorithm vs me giving you the correct implementation.

“What I learned on my own I still remember”